# The best way to play videos on website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

According to a [Post from w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp), the best way to play videos on a website is to use HTML5 with fallbacks below:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <object data="movie.mp4" width="320" height="240">
    <embed src="movie.swf" width="320" height="240">
  </object>
Please update your browser. Thanks!
</video>
```

I have tried to use the code above, and it works on Chrome. Also with IE9. But when my client sent me a feedback, he says the video is not playing on his IE8 browser. So I checked and used IE8 and it does fail. I could tell him to upgrade his browser but that won't work with all users viewing the website.

So I switched to youtube solution, from [w3schools' post](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp). Now it's playing on his IE8 (hurray!). But a new problem arise. The video can't be played on his iPad. Possibly he got his youtube app disabled.

I also tried using my iPad. Suprisingly, it didn't worked too (shocking!).

---

**Problem:**

What's the very best way to play videos on a website? Maybe not a 100% fail-free solution but would play on most cases.

**Criteria:**

- Autoplay
- Cross-browser (including Android's default browser)
- No to ready-made plug-ins/players
- Large video file (50MB+)

Comment: I don't have my iPad here so can't test this but have you read this? : http://www.satsig.net/images/youtube-on-ipad.htm

Its quite an old post but seems a simple fix if it works.

Comment: [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/)

Comment: @Izion I also have tried that. Adding 'http:' instead of '//www.youtube.com'. Produced same output.

Comment: @nietonfir tried that one too.

Comment: @Erick Works like a charm. Just used it today in a microsite with different versions (mobile/streaming version with ~15MB and a full HD desktop one with ~40MB, both H264) of a video. No problems on most browsers (IE7+, FF, Chrome, iOS, Android, …). Autoplay doesn't work on mobile obviously, but that's a browser feature to prevent data hogs - you need a user initiated event there. And concerning your iPad issue: the video NEEDS to have a proper ratio + supported encoding, else it just won't play. Maybe that helps …

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no single way to do this cross-browser.

[First, there is not a single HTML5-video-codec that works on all browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_video#Browser_support)

Second, IE8 does not support HTML5, so it's not possible without ready-made plug-ins/players like Flash

Third, you can't just use Flash on all devices, because that doesn't work on the Apple iMonopolyPad & iHegemonyPhone, because apple can't allow it because they a) want to sell Quick-Time video and b) don't wan't a competing adobe-appstore which would be much better than their own on their own platform, because that cuts their profit margins.

Youtube videos are not all converted into non-flash HTML5-video-formats, and HTML5 video might be disabled per youtube/google account.

So, if you want to embed it, you best use a jQuery plugin.
Then you can declare a div with a width and a height, and a class, and a data-attribute for the video URL, and jQuery substitutes the div with the appropriate HTML5 video-tag for each browser, or with Flash in IE8.

What comes closest to your wishes is [this](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody):

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls>
    <!-- MP4 must be first for iPad! -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.MP4" type="video/mp4" /><!-- Safari / iOS video    -->
    <source src="__VIDEO__.OGV" type="video/ogg" /><!-- Firefox / Opera / Chrome10 -->
    <!-- fallback to Flash: -->
    <object width="640" height="360" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="__FLASH__.SWF">
        <!-- Firefox uses the `data` attribute above, IE/Safari uses the param below -->
        <param name="movie" value="__FLASH__.SWF" />
        <param name="flashvars" value="controlbar=over&amp;image=__POSTER__.JPG&amp;file=__VIDEO__.MP4" />
        <!-- fallback image. note the title field below, put the title of the video there -->
        <img src="__VIDEO__.JPG" width="640" height="360" alt="__TITLE__"
             title="No video playback capabilities, please download the video below" />
    </object>

   <track src="subtitles_en.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" label="English">
   <track src="subtitles_no.vtt" kind="subtitles" srclang="no" label="Norwegian">
</video>
```

A good format-converter for the babylonian codec & resolution plage is this one:
http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/

And use the GNU file (libmagic) utility to check whether your file is actually of the format specified in the file's extension.